# Can $60+60\times0+1$ be both $1$ and $61$

Tags: notation, arithmetic

The expression under debate is $60+60\times0+1$.

I'm in a debate on Facebook and people that are saying $61$ and that the people that are saying $1$ are and vice versa but I'm saying they are both right it all depends on how the math problem is done whether you use PEMDAS or you don't. Who is right in the equation?

Comment: Why would you be justified to not use pemdas?

Comment: Pemdas is completely universal in standard arithmetic. There is no reason you wouldn't use it here.

Comment: if you are going to ignore standard order of operations, then reverse it, and the value is $(60+60)\times(0+1)=120$. But ignoring the standard meaning of things is like inventing your own language. The answer to the above could be Aardvark, if you want to invent your own language.

Answer (score 3):

You have to agree on a convention and in standard arithmetic, order of operations is part of that convention. Therefore, $60 + 60 \times 0 + 1 = 60 + 1 = 61$ and that's the end of the story.

If you wanted, you could define a new "universe" where you don't follow the order of operations and instead move from left to right. But without specifically saying you are working in this (probably lonely) universe, you should assume it's standard arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of explicit grouping to resolve the apparent ambiguities, the expression as written means
$$(60+(60\times 0))+1$$ which is $61$.

Grouping symbols must be explicitly introduced to alter the order of operations. In particular,
$$((60+60)\times 0)+1$$ is $1$.